# How to bind an Event Handler with "delegate()" using an attribute filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Want to attach an Event Handler/Listener to some links using the "delegate()" method, but I want to attach it only to links with certain classes:

The links are inside a larger block called "slider", so what I use to bind the Event Listener to all the links is:

$("#slider").delegate("a", "click", myFunction);

But I want to bind the #slider method to only the links that have a class that does NOT contain "nivo-control".

```
$("#slider").delegate("a[class!='nivo-control']", "click", myFunction);
```

it doesn't work, not even for the links that ONLY have a class of "nivo-control".

```
$("#slider a").delegate("a[class!='nivo-control']", "click", myFunction);
```

doesn't work either.

I could also select the links by checking whether they do NOT have a "rel" attribute, but this doesn't work either:

```
$("#slider").delegate("a[rel!='']", "click", function() { alert("hey");});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following filter/selector you may try.

```
$( "#slider" ).delegate( "a:not(.nivo-control)", "click", handler );
```